# Not generating email alerts in Bitnami Redmine Stack version 4.0.5

Tags: email, redmine, bitnami, alerts

I have installed Bitnami Redmine Stack Version 4.0.5. All the functions working fine, except email alerts. Did some changes to default configurations in configuration.yml as below to fix, but no any response.

```rb
# Outgoing emails configuration
# See the examples below and the Rails guide for more configuration options:
# http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration
    production:
    email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp

     enable_starttls_auto:true
     smtp_settings:
       address: 10.50.30.1
       port: 25
     domain:"redmine@abc.lk"

      # authentication: :login
      # user_name: 
      # password:
```

wants to send mail alerts through outlook.office.com server.

Did some changes to default configurations in configuration.yml as below to fix, but no any response.
Did nothing in Ruby files.
also the mail server access also finely working